# Determine the caller of the page which has common page as composition

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

[image]

Assume I'm in page:
I clicked on "Create book" link, takes me to Book Creator page and when I click on start Book creator, it returns me Main page

Assume I'm in some search result page:
I clicked on "Create book" link, takes me to Book Creator page and when I click on start Book creator, it returns me search result page

you can test this scenario in link [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Same in code:

```
public class CommonItem {
    Class<?> Calle
    CommonItem(Class<?> Calle) { 
       this.calle = calle;
    }

    public PageX clickLink() {
       return new PageX(Class<?> Calle);
    }

}



public class PageA {
    // WebDriver driver;
    CommonItem ci;

    PageA() {
        ci = new CommonItem(PageA.class);
    }

    public PageX commonItemClick() {
        PageX axp = ci.clickLink();
        return axp;
    }
}


public class PageB {
    CommonItem ci;

    PageB() {
        ci = new CommonItem(PageB.class);
    } 

    public PageX commonItemClick() {
        PageX bxp = ci.clickLink();
        return bxp;
    }
} 


    public class PageX {
      Class<?> calle;
      PageX(Class<?> calle){
            this.calle = calle;
      }
    public void someLink() {
        // Click some Link here
        // return pageA or PageB (depends on which page called this method,  How to determine? )                  
       return calle;
   }
}
```

Update-1: I've implemented suggestion above.
Now I've a test method
which calls pageX.someLink() method, returns PageA or PageB,syntax would be

```
PageX xp = pageA.commonItemClick();
Class<?> caller = xp.someLink();
// how to access method of page A via caller variable ?
```

Comment: Add a Class<?> callee field to the CommonItem class, change or add another constructor to get the value of this callee field and initialize it. So your PageA constructor will have new CommonItem(PageA.class) line. Now CommonItem class knows which class created an object of it.

Comment: Added Update-1 to the question. Not sure, how to access outcome page method.

Answer (score 0):

From web point of view you may try executing script "window.history.go(-1)" on click of any link or button.

Regarding the java code, the class *CommonItem* can have a constructor that takes a parameter as to who created it, which can later be used to determine the back-page.